# input values and submit button in link

Tags: php, html, input

Is it possible to make link with some attribute from input elements on website? E.g. I have site with code like this:

```
<input class="input-text " type="number" name="your-number" value="11">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="download" value="download file">
```

I would like to have link something like http://example.com?value=11&submit=download which set "11" in input-number and clicked button. Is it possible? Just by go to link like this?

Comment: This is definitely possible, you could use the `$_GET` method to achieve what you are trying to. Check this link out at W3 schools. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm too weak to understand this. But really thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome, once you play around with the code a little, you will find its very easy to implement. You will get there!